# MVP. Обработка лонг клика

Tags: android, mvp

Пытаюсь применить паттерн MVP.
Есть активити, в ней есть кнопка, при длительном(3сек) нажатии на кнопку - должно произойти определенное действие.

Вопрос:

Где обрабатывать длительное нажатие? Т.е. считать эти 3сек.

1. В самой активити. Вешать слушателя и отсчитывать 3сек. Если 3сек прошли - передавать событие в презентер, что кнопка нажата. (я склоняюсь к этому)
2. В презентере. Передавать в презентер событие ACTION_DOWN & ACTION_UP и в нем считать 3сек.

Comment: а чем стандартный onLongClickListener не устраивает?

Comment: @plesser а там разве можно указать сколько нужно секунд, чтобы сработал клик ?

Comment: Там нельзя, но тебе же надо просто длительное нажатие как я понимаю. А по времени колхоз будет...

Comment: @plesser не совсем. Я указал, что нужно длительное нажатие на 3сек. Не 2, не 5)